What type should I specify to receive an OpenCV 4.1.2 image from python using SWIG 4?
I'm writting a C++ library that analyzes images using OpenCV. In order to achieve that, I'm using opencv-swig for generating python bindings of that library. However, when I call the module from python, it isn't able to find the adequate method for the provided arguments:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/config/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/example.py", line 12422, in opencv_receiver
    return _libReconDMI.opencv_receiver(image)
TypeError: in method 'opencv_receiver', argument 1 of type 'cv::Mat'

In C++, opencv_receiver is implemented as shown below:
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"

void opencv_receiver(cv::Mat image){
    (void)image;
}

According to answers like Returning a Opencv Mat type from my Python Code , opencv-swig should be able to generate those bindings. As a consequence, I'm not sure if this problem is a result of using opencv 4.1.2 and swig 4.0.2 as it seems that passing images worked with previous versions of them.
Do you know if opencv-swig requires using a different type in order to receive images?
Is there an alternative way to interface a C++ module that requires receiving OpenCV images which supports newest versions of OpenCV? (For example using numpy.i interface to receive a numpy array containing the image and converting it to a cv::Mat object in C++)
Minimal reproducible example:
In order to reproduce this problem, a minimal project that builds the previously described function was provided here: https://github.com/renatoGarcia/opencv-swig/issues/31#issuecomment-2065932116
Platform details:

Code server docker image: lscr.io/linuxserver/code-server:latest (https://docs.linuxserver.io/images/docker-code-server/)
OS: Ubuntu Jammy (according to https://docs.linuxserver.io/FAQ/)
Compiler: gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
Conan version: 2.2.2
Python version: 3.10.12
SWIG version: 4.0.2

Update (06/05/2024):
If I generate an image from my module using the following function other functions are able to read it:
cv::Mat testReturn(){
            cv::Mat img1(500, 1000, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(10, 100, 150));
            return img1;
        }

Calling that function without storing the result in a variable shows <example.Mat; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'cv::Mat *' at 0x7f4b1b3e31e0> >.
However, if I try to call opencv functions using that image from python, an error is raised. For example, if I try to apply an Otsu threshold to that image using ret2, reference_image_bin_1 = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU), the following error is raised:
>>> ret2, reference_image_bin_1 = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'threshold'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Changing the type of the generated image to cv::UMat didn't fix this, but it seems that I'm not using the same object type that opencv uses for storing images in python variables

welcome. solutions don't go into the question. you post them as an answer. [tour]

Thanks for pointing it out, I'll delete it as I have alredy written it as an answer

Opencv-swig requires converting opencv objects to an internal class of the generated module. This can be achieved by using module_name.Mat.from_array(OpenCV_image). Then, the result needs to be converted to an opencv compatible object using numpy.asarray(module_image)
